Integral inequality with exact values of a function
$f(x)$ is non-zero continuously differentiable function. Prove that $$\int\limits_1^2 x(f'(x))^2 dx +2f(1)f(2)>0$$
I tried to use Cauchy–Schwarz integral inequality. I also tried integration by parts and some algebraic transformations. I don't know what else should I try.

It suffices to check it for polynomial f which are dense in the set of functions you consider.

To relate $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ to the derivative $f'$ it is probably a good idea to use the fundamental theorem of calculus: $$\tag{1} f(2) - f(1) = \int_1^2 f'(x) \, dx.$$ This can be bounded above using Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$\tag{2}\int_1^2 f'(x) \, dx = \int_1^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \left( \sqrt x f'(x)\right) \, dx \le \left( \int_1^2 \frac 1x \, dx \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_1^2 x f'(x)^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2}.$$ Square (1) and (2) to find
$$\left( f(2) - f(1)\right)^2 = \left( \int_1^2 f'(x) \, dx \right)^2 \le \ln 2 \int_1^2 x f'(x)^2 \, dx.$$ Expand the left hand side to discover
$$f(1)^2 + f(2)^2 \le 2f(1)f(2) + \ln 2 \int_1^2 x f'(x)^2 \, dx.$$ This leads directly to what you are looking to prove.

[+1] Excellent answer !

@Umberto P. thank you so much!
